# JPA: how to save date timestamp in MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, eclipselink

I have an issue in saving offset in MySQL. I am using JPA 2.0 + EclipseLink.

Here is the code which I tried:

```
        @Entity
        @Table(name="log")
        public class Log {

            @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
            @Column(name="launchactivity", nullable=true)
            private Date launchActivity;

            //setter and getter
        }
```

My client is sending the `java.util.Date` as in format of **(2013-12-03T19:32:16.413+05:30) 'yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ'**, but MySQL is saving the `java.util.Date` as **"2013-12-02 19:32:16.0"**. With this offset is missing. How do I save time zone and time zoneoffset?

Comment: java.util.Date can not be a string. can you post an http://sscce.org/

Comment: @vels4j We can convert Date to String using SimpleDateFormat.

Comment: I know but your question may not help anyone to give u an answer

Comment: You cannot "send" a `java.util.Date` in a specific "format". A `java.util.Date` does not have a format, it's basically a `long` value wrapped into a class. So what exactly do you get from "the client"? An instance of `java.util.Date` (then your claim regarding the format is wrong) or do you actually get a `String` instance with the stated format?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name My Client just sends the date in the format which I specified above. I convert the string to Date on my server end (My server is written using Jersey Restful) and then save the object.

Comment: So your client *is* sending a `String` not a `Date`. How exactly are you converting that String to a date? Btw: you can not save a timestampt with a timezone in MySQL - that is simply not supported. You must extract the timezone from the string and store it in a separate column together with the timestamp as UTC